# Setting Landscape Orientation for Galleria

Tags: javascript, html, galleria

I am using Galleria for displaying images in a mobile device and I have configured it to show images with a preview option in the bottom.

I could not find a way to set the orientation of the plugin. Ideally I would like it to be landscape by default, please note the rest of my application is in portrait. I just want it to be landscape for the plugin. Is there some way to achieve this through overriding the plugin in some way?

Comment: What is the difference between the landscape version and the portrait? couldn't find anything about that on the website

Comment: The images I am using would look better in landscape. So if I can force the images to be in landscape mode it would look better